# Cannot send password reset link from laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, email

As titled, I cannot get Laravel to send password reset emails. I am using the "out of the box" auth command to handle the password reset and I put in all the details from the email account I set up in cpanel. Laravel will authenticate the details ok and will tell me the reset link has been sent ok but the email hasn't been sent from the mail account and it doesn't show in the target email either. don't know what I've done wrong but here's my code section from the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=n3plcpnl0067.prod.ams3.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=**account address**
MAIL_PASSWORD=**acount password**
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and from the mail.php file:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'n3plcpnl0067.prod.ams3.secureserver.net'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Password reset'),
    ],
```

It works fine when I use the dummy account on mailtrap, just not with the email set up in cpanel for my hosting

Comment: try with mail driver as `'sendmail'` or `'mail'`, you won't need to setup smtp, assuming your app in running from cpanel itself.

Comment: No that didn't work I'm afraid

Comment: your app is running from cpanel right? and is it that no email works or its just this reset link one"

Comment: Yeah from cpanel. I only have the password reset one to check right now

Comment: I hope you have cleared all other fields, as with mail and sendmail you don't need to pass any host or credentials, can you make sure all of them are empty?

Comment: Sorry when you say clear them do you mean in the env file or mail.php?

Comment: clear them both, just to be sure

Comment: yeah its ok, I sorted it. Thanks for the advice